Examples of variance (Jon Skeet book)
Is it correct, that second example in the book has direction from dynamic to object? First example has direction from string to object, I thought that second one will be from object to dynamic.

To put this into a concrete example, let’s consider Func<in T, out TResult>. The rules mean the following:

There’s a valid conversion from Func<object, int> to Func<string, int> because

The first type parameter is contravariant, and there’s an implicit reference conversion from string to object.
The second type parameter is covariant, and there’s an identity conversion from int to int.


There’s a valid conversion from Func<dynamic, string> to Func<object, IConvertible> because

The first type parameter is contravariant,    and there’s an identity conversion from dynamic to object.
The second type parameter is covariant, and there’s an implicit reference    conversion from string to IConvertible




— Code snippet taken from Book "C# in Depth" fourth edition by J. Skeet, page 147.

what exactly is your question? Why do you think it should be the other way round? A Func<T, TResult> is contravariant in T, and covariant in TResult. In your case that means every object can be passed to your Func, as object is convertible to dynamic. And every string is an IConvertible., so you can return a string from a Func returning IConvertible.

Conversion between object and dynamic is identity, so the direction is not important, but this is not rigorous enough here.

See the spec, second bullet point. There is an identity conversion between object and dynamic, which means that there is an identity conversion from object to dynamic, and a symmetric identity conversion from dynamic to object. Here it's the identity conversion from dynamic to object which is relevant

Why does it matter? Identity conversions are symmetric anyway. An identity conversion from A to B implies one from B to A.

Contravariance
For simplicity, let's consider delegate taking only parameter: Action<in TParam>. We can think about it as a method:
void SomeMethod(TParam param);

or more concretely:
void SomeMethod(string param);

so it is perfectly valid to assign such method to variable, for example and call it:
Action<string> action = SomeMethod;
action("some value");

Now, let's think about action variable - it accepts string param, but what if the variable held reference to Action<object>? Like below:
// Note changed type of param
void SomeMethod(object param);

Action<string> action = SomeMethod;
// IMPORTANT - this is still perfectly valid
action("some value");

It would still work, as action is declared as method accepting only string, so what is under the hood (what is true type param) does not really worries us, as long as string is derived from that type.
And this is what contravariance is all about, the line
Action<string> action = SomeMethod;

is still valid, if SomeMethod has object type for its parameter.
Covariance
Is much simplier. Let's consider for simplicity Func<out TResult>.
TResult is return type for delegate. So if method returns object, it could also return less derived type, and the result could be still assignable to the base type, i.e.:
Func<object> d1 = () => new object();
Func<string> d2 = () => "covariance";

Now, when you call d1() you expect to get an object, when you call d2() you expect to get a string. Since string is derived from object, caller of d1 would not break if the method returns more derived type (such as string). So the assignment:
d1 = d2;

Would work, as return types would be still compatible.
And this works thanks to covariance (another example could be with collections).
Putting it all together
I hope that it is clear, that now Func<TInput, TResult> and other delegates (with more type params) is just some combination of my explanations above :)
Coming back to your question. First type parameter in Func delegates (when there's two ore more type params), is contravariant (with in modifier). Meaning that less derived type there can be assigned to variable defined with more derived type. So:

Func<object, int> to Func<string, int> - correct, as Func<object, int> could be assigned to any Func<whatever, int>, because whatever is derived from object

Func<dynamic, string> to Func<object, IConvertible> - correct, as Func<dynamic, int> could be assigned to any Func<object, int>, because object is assignable to dynamic.



@MakePeaceGreatAgain good catch. Thanks

Is it correct steps if we talk about Func<object, int> to Func<string, int>?

Func<object, int> objFunc = obj => ... // some code ... ;
Func<string, int> strFunc = objFunc; // conversion to  Func<string, int> 
strFunc("Test"); // invocation
strFunc has input parameter that is treated like string, but actually it object type. There is conversion of argument ("Test" in this example) from type string to object type.  Because any string is derived form object all is valid.


@Alfredo correct
